# gnome screen brightness

Tags: gnome, kernel, brightness, mac

When pressing the brightness keys (or using the slider in settings) Ubuntu acts as if it's changing the screen brightness but the brightness does not change.
By poking around I found that I can change the brightness with

```
echo $N > /sys/class/backlight/radeon_bl0/brightness
```

where $N is >= 0 and $N <= 255.

- iMac=mc813ll/a
- Ubuntu Release=18.04
- Kernel=4.15.0-20-generic (default)

relevant log excerpt;

```
> tail -n 2 /var/log/auth.log
May  5 11:44:02 imac pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
May  5 11:44:02 imac pkexec[7310]: $USER: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/$USER] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-backlight-helper --set-brightness 10]
```

direct test;

```
> sudo /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-backlight-helper --set-brightness 255
Could not set the value of the backlight: writing '255' to /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/backlight/acpi_video0 failed
```

No man pages

```
> man gsd-backlight-helper
No manual entry for gsd-backlight-helper
> man gnome-settings-daemon
No manual entry for gnome-settings-daemon
```

longer path examples;

```
> echo 20 > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
-bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument

> echo 20 > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/radeon_bl0/brightness
```

looks like [this](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/blob/ed7c2744aca1ad0bdd5adb62a8f2b5bdc1eb94b4/plugins/power/gsd-backlight-linux.c#L83) is the src, how do I tell the GNOME brightness what to talk to in the kernel?

[EDIT]
I just rebooted and

```
/sys/class/backlight/radeon_bl0/brightness
```

is now

```
/sys/class/backlight/radeon_bl1/brightness
```

or

```
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/drm/card1/card1-eDP-1/radeon_bl1
```

so the location is not even stable.

```
> lspci | grep "VGA compatible controller"
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6730M/6770M/7690M XT]

> sudo dmidecode | grep -A 9 "System Information" | grep "Product Name"
    Product Name: iMac12,2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [acpi_backlight](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt) kernel parameter;

```
 sudo perl -pi -e 's/(GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="[^"]*)(")/$1 acpi_backlight=vendor$2/g' /etc/default/grub
```

Comment: 2 years later and this saved me hours of googling. Thanks for posting the solution!